# How to range over slice of structs instead of struct of slices

Tags: html, templates, go, struct, go-templates

Having played around with Go HTML templates a bit, all the examples I found for looping over objects in templates were passing structs of slices to the template, somewhat like in this example :

```
type UserList struct {
    Id   []int
    Name []string
}

var templates = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("main.html"))

func rootHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    users := UserList{
        Id:   []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
        Name: []string{"user0", "user1", "user2", "user3", "user4"},
    }
    templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "main", &users)
}
```

with the "main" template being :

```
{{define "main"}}
    {{range .Name}}
        {{.}}
    {{end}}
{{end}}
```

This works, but i don't understand how I'm supposed to display each ID just next to its corresponding Name if i'm ranging on the .Name property only. I would find it more logical to treat each user as an object to group its properties when displaying.

Thus my question:

**What if I wanted to pass a slice of structs to the template?** What would be the syntax to make this work? I haven't found or understood how to in the official html/template doc.
I imagined something looking remotely like this:

```
type User struct {
    Id   int
    Name string
}
type UserList []User
var myuserlist UserList = ...
```

and a template looking somewhat like this: (syntax here is deliberately wrong, it's just to get understood)

```
{{define "main"}}
    {{for each User from myuserlist as myuser}}
        {{myuser.Id}}
        {{myuser.Name}}
    {{end}}
{{end}}
```

Comment: Read this: http://jan.newmarch.name/go/template/chapter-template.html - specifically, assign one to a variable that you can call from within the range loop.

Comment: That seems to be quite complete on the subject, i'll be sure to read all of it very soon. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, it even had the answer to problems i guessed i would run into later. Thanks for this great link.

Comment: @elithrar , can you add a valid URL?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use:

```
{{range .}}
    {{.Id}}
    {{.Name}}
{{end}}
```

for the template.
Here is a example: http://play.golang.org/p/A4BPJOcfpB
You need to read more about the "dot" in the package overview to see how to properly use this. http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#pkg-overview (checkout the Pipelines part)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the rep to comment, but to answer @ROMANIA_engineer, the source cited by elithrar has been retired, for anyone still looking for this reference :

> This book has been removed as it will shortly be published by APress. Please see [Network Programming with Go: Essential Skills for Using and Securing Networks](http://www.apress.com/us/book/9781484226919)