# How to pass a slice of structs to template and iterate them in Golang?

Tags: templates, go, struct, slice, go-templates

I want to pass **a slice** that contains **structs** and display all of them in the view.

```
type Person struct {
    ID   int
    NAME string
}
```

Example of a slice of structs

```
 [{1 John},{2, Mary},{3, Steven},{4, Mike}]
```

What I want in
**index.html**

```
1 - John
2 - Mary
3 - Steven
4 - Mike
```

Comment: Use the range action. Go to https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/ and ctrl+f for `range`.

Comment: I found a relevant post and I solved it.
Thank you guys. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24556001/go-templates-range-over-slice-of-structs-instead-of-struct-of-slices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a relevant post and I solved it.
Thank you guys.

[Go templates : range over slice of structs instead of struct of slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24556001/go-templates-range-over-slice-of-structs-instead-of-struct-of-slices)

So as mkopriva mentioned, use range action.